# Проблема с работой с файлами в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы

Пишу простейшую функцию:

```py
def load(path):
    with open(path, "r+") as stckFile:
        stck = stckFile.read()
    return stck
```

Однако, не видит в упор файлы.
К примеру, пишу:

```py
data = load('file.txt')
print(data)
```

Выдает ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/dotco/Desktop/stck/stck/dictionary.py", line 19, in <module>
    data = load('file.txt')
  File "c:/Users/dotco/Desktop/stck/stck/dictionary.py", line 2, in load
    with open(path, "r+") as stckFile:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'file.txt'
```

Подскажите решение данной проблемы.
Ее, конечно, можно решить, указав в функции load() параметр path как r("тут_полный_путь_к_файлу").
Но меня интересует только короткая запись.

Структура "проекта":

```
stck
    stck
        dictionary.py
        file.txt
```

Comment: вы запускали тот код, который написан в вопросе?

Comment: если вы хотите добиться помощи, то вам стоило указать, где лежат какие файлы

Comment: код работает как надо, только что заменил `def load():` на `def load(path):` при этом файл тхт находится на одном уровне с скриптом

Comment: Да, именно так функция и написана. Ошибка в вопросе. Структура та же что и у вас. (@Vadim.Sharoikin)

Comment: @Shift единственное что могу предположить что какая-нибудь ошибка в названии файла, на подобие руская буквва е или х вместо англ

Comment: К сожалению, нет. Название написано корректно.

Comment: Возможно текущая директория для скрипта не совпадает с директорией, где лежит скрипт. Такое может быть если скрипт запущен из командной строки с указанием полного пути. Также vscode запускает скрипты из домашней директории пользователя.

Comment: Действительно. Попробовал запустить скрипт через стандартный терминал. Сработало. Спасибо